# Replacing a beacon by a Bookmark in word using excel vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am developping an excel macro and i need to replace a specific word (beacon) in my .docx by a bookmark, i found this on the microsoft site.

```
Sub BMark() 
 ' Select some text in the active document prior 
 ' to execution. 
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add _ 
 Name:="tableauxvdd", Range:=Selection.Range 
End Sub
```

But i dont know how to fix the range, i have the idea to select the word with smthg like that :

```
        With word_fichier.Application.Selection.Find
            .Forward = True
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute FindText:="#tableauxvdd"
        End With
```

But it need a range and not a selection.

Comment: Look back at the code you posted from the MS site: `Range:=` **Selection.Range**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
        With word_fichier.Range
            With .Find
              .ClearFormatting
              .Replacement.ClearFormatting
              .Text = "#tableauxvdd"
              .Replacement.Text = ""
              .Forward = True
              .Wrap = wdFindStop
              .Format = False
              .MatchWildcards = True
              .Execute
            End With
            If .Find.Found = True Then .Bookmarks.Add Name:="tableauxvdd", Range:=.Duplicate
        End With
```

**Note:** As I commented in your other thread, and as demonstrated above, there is no need to use 'Selection' at all for what you are doing.

Comment: i didnt think about that, ill try that later, thanks

Comment: it's working like a charm, thanks a lot ! but i dont understand the line Range = .Duplicate

Comment: So look up .Duplicate!